# MVC Razor RadioButtonFor: How to have NO preset @checked?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, checked, radiobuttonfor

```
@for (var b = 0; b < 11; b++)
  {
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.LikelyToReturn, @b, new { @checked = false })
  }
```

If I leave out

```
new { @checked = false }
```

then the first radio button is checked by default.  If I include it, the last is checked by default.  How would I have NONE of them checked by default?

**EDIT AFTER:**

This is the model:

```
public class PatientSatisfactionSurveyPage : Page
{
   //non important stuff removed
   public int LikelyToReturn { get; set; }
   public PatientSatisfactionSurveyPage() { }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this with my own testing.

The reason the last radio button is selected is because of your `checked = false`.  The presence of the `checked` attribute means that the radio button is supposed to be checked.  You could have something like `checked = "casey-is-awesome!"` and one of the radio buttons in the group would be selected.

If you don't want any of the button selected then simply omit the checked attribute entirely.  If you're still having issues please post your model and any related controller code.

**Edit**

Change

`public int LikelyToReturn { get; set; }`

to

`public int? LikelyToReturn { get; set; }`.

`int` has a default value of 0. Since 0 is being used as the value of the first radio button, the ASP.NET MVC framework is automatically marking it as selected since that value matches the value in the model. By switching to a nullable int the default value will be null and thus the framework won't automatically mark it selected

Comment: Thanks Justin.  Yeah, I'm sure that when the "new { @checked = false }" is removed, the first radio button is selected.  i added the model to the OP.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Change `public int LikelyToReturn { get; set; }` to `public int? LikelyToReturn { get; set; }`.  `int` has a default value of 0.  Since 0 is being used as the value of the first radio button, the ASP.NET MVC framework is automatically marking it as selected since that value matches the value in the model.  By switching to a nullable int the default value will be null and thus the framework won't automatically mark it selected.

Answer (score 1):

A default value of integer is 0 so it always select first one whose value is also 0. To get your result you have to set `Model.LikelyToReturn` is nullable.

```
public class yourClassName
{
    public int? LikelyToReturn { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This won't fix the issue.  Even if you used a `bool?` the issue still exists.  Also, `bool?` is null by default, so setting the value to null in the constructor isn't needed.

Comment: Also, I can't have it be a bool because this is not a yes/no answer. There are 10 possible radio buttons to select from, so LikelyToReturn  must be set to an int.